# Following OSX 10.9 upgrade, Console App won't tail after waking from sleep

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, console

I use Console.App to tail log files. However, after upgrading to Mavericks, once my MBP wakes from sleep, the app won't refresh automatically. It works fine when I first launch the app.

If I click Refresh, it will bring the log up to date. Disabling and then enabling Now has the same effect, but it will not continue to tail. If I close the app and reopen it, it works fine again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Mine does this as well. And not necessarily after sleep. All the time. :(

Comment: @Fuzzy76 I switched to Terminal: `tail -F MyLogFile.txt`